# About RC4 Decryption PHP (mcrypt)

Tags: php

I'm looking for anything about RC4 Decryption with decode the input using: Hexa

Lucky for me, I found
[PHP's mcrypt_encrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php).

I want to decrypt many cipher files with the same key.
But, I had a problem with:

```
$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_ARCFOUR, MCRYPT_MODE_STREAM); 
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND); 
print (mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_ARCFOUR, $key, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_STREAM, $iv));
```

(And UTF-8 Vietnamese)

The result of `echo $iv_size` is `0`.

Please help me, I don't know how I can fix it?

> Key : Lyr1cjust4nct  (key file .txt)
>
> Mode: STREAM
>
> Decode the input using: Hexa
>
> Ciphertext: cipher.txt (Hexa)
>
> http://pastebin.com/bmYcmU0J

Comment: Why tagged with java?

Comment: Don't use RC4 (aka ARC4, ARCFOUR), it is not secure, use AES (Advanced Encryption Standard).

Comment: My problem is : I have some files .txt, database encrypted RC4 (my post), I want to do automatic like tool online [link](https://www.tools4noobs.com/online_tools/decrypt)

Answer (score 1):

RC4 doesn't support IVs. You instead need to use a unique key for each message.

RC4 has two big weaknesses that apply to your situation:

- Using related keys is not secure. So you can't just concatenate a fixed key with a variable/unique IV. You'd need to use some kind of hashing scheme.
- The beginning of the output is very biased, which leaks information about the ciphertext. So you need to throw away the beginning of the key-stream. I think throwing away 1024 bytes should take care of the biggest biases.

RC4 doesn't include any integrity protection (MAC). So if an attacker manipulates the ciphertext, you'll run into problems.

=> **Don't use RC4.** Use AES in an authenticated mode such as GCM or by combining AES with a MAC using the encrypt-then-MAC principle.

I strongly recommend using a high level library written by experts, since people get encryption wrong very often, even when using standard primitives like AES.

Comment: What do you think about

Comment: `function decryptArc4($key, $data) {
    $iv = ""; // Empty init vector.
    return mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_ARCFOUR, $key, $data,    MCRYPT_MODE_STREAM, $iv);
}`

Comment: @HungVo Why use an insecure encryption method?

Comment: @HungVo 1) You didn't include how you derive the unique per message key. 2) It still doesn't drop the initial keystream 3) Why would you use RC4 in a new system in 2016? It's slow, hard to use and still relatively weak when used properly. 4) **DON'T USE RC4**

Comment: My problem is : I have some files .txt, database encrypted RC4 (my post), I want to do automatic like tool online                           [link](https://www.tools4noobs.com/online_tools/decrypt)